# In OpenGL ES for Android, what is the optimal way to translate objects onto a map?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I've begun working with android, so I'm developing a little game (mostly for learning purposes).  My game has a simple 2d non-scrolling map, and I have many objects that will be placed in the map.  The objects are already modeled statically in their classes, and I understand how to shift these into a float buffer and send them to the shaders.

I understand the gist of the model, view, and project matrices, but I've heard that translating in the shader, or passing specific model matrices for each object is inefficient.

How do I, optimally, take the modeled objects, and place them in the appropriate spot on the map (world coordinates)?  Where should that translate occur (before or durring shaders?  As part of the model matrix?)

(Pseudo-code is sufficient for an answer if necessary.)

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean sending the MVP matrix to the shader or using glTranslate, glRotate, etc.... as being inefficient?

Comment: I was told that because each time a uniform is changed, the pipeline has to be flushed, and it slows performance.  I'm not sure how to go about it short of that... so I thought maybe I just don't understand the process and should ask.

Comment: It really depends where you want to do the calculations, it's entirely possible to just translate the vertices on the CPU and send them to the shader to avoid this but the shader is much better suited to this task anyway. In OpenGL 4 the convention is to send the MVP to the shader anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all comes down to the ratio of how many vertices (of a model) come to a single translation (change of transformation). As a general rule, for rendering the bulk of geometry, about at least 100 vertices should be sent for a given uniform if you want to max out the pipeline. Note that if your total number of vertices is relatively small about below 10000, you'll probably not notice any performance penality on modern systems.

So, if your objects are nontrivial, i.e. have a significant number of vertices, changing the uniforms is the way to go. If your objects are simple, placing them into a shared Vertex Array, with an additional vertex attribute indexing into a uniform arrays of transformations will make better use of the pipeline.

It really depends on how complex your objects are.